# How can I redirect Joomla 2.5 SEF urls

Tags: .htaccess, joomla2.5

Recently updated a site to Joomla 2.5.  The client wanted to change a url from example.com/products to example.com/solutions.

There are external links to example.com/products which now throws a 404.

I have tried a number of .htaccess redirect rules with no success including:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^products/(.*) http://www.example.com/solutions/ [R=301,L]
```

Anyone else had this issue?